# Recursive class template and implicit instantiation error in C++

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, language-lawyer

The following minimal reproducible example contains a template `struct B` with default argument type containing a lambda `A<[]{ return 1; }>`, `B` is recursively inherited from `B<>`. And there is a specialization of `B` for any `A<z>`.

```
template<auto>
struct A{};

template<class = A<[]{ return 1; }>>
struct B : B<> {};

template<auto z>
struct B<A<z>> {};

B<int> x;
```

GCC is ok with the example, by Clang complains:

```
error: implicit instantiation of template 'B<A<{}>>' within its own definition
```

Demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/xzjzo7dE9

Which compiler is right here?

P.S. If one modifies the definition of `B` this way:

```
template<class>
struct B : B<A<[]{ return 1; }>> {};
```

then all compilers become totally happy, demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/roqnc39eq

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Which compiler is right here?

Both are, since `B` is ill-formed; NDR. As always, [temp.res]/8 applies:

> The validity of a template may be checked prior to any instantiation. The program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required, if:
>
> [(8.4)](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp.res#general-8.4) - a hypothetical instantiation of a template immediately following its definition would be ill-formed due to a construct that does not depend on a template parameter, or

The template is `B`, and "its" definition here speaks of the primary. If we were to instantiate `B<>` immediately after, we'll get an unconditionally ill-formed class definition. Hence, GCC and Clang can do whatever.

Btw, this entire lambda as a template argument business is a red herring. We can go for plain, old int as parameter and get similar divergence as well.

```
template<int>
struct A{};

template<class = A<0>>
struct B : B<> {};

template<int z>
struct B<A<z>> {};

B<int> x;

int main() {}
```

Clang still complains, but now [so does GCC](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGE6a4AMngMmAByPgBGmMQSZqQADqgKhE4MHt6%2BekkpjgLBoREs0bFctpj2eQxCBEzEBBk%2BflLllWk1dQQF4VExcba19Y1ZZQqDXSE9xX1cAJS2qF7EyOwcBJgsCQbrJgDMbiEEe9gmGgCCY8ReDgDUZyYA7FYPACJ7VuenZ%2Bub25h7bmQBgUChuexedwBGmOMPOl2uBBuFhuICRAOOYKejzeuw%2B93OPy2TB2%2B0ONwAXrCLgQrrcrPt7vtKbsTizMc8cXivvSDoIMap3l8vmSWEwQhBZuzsV8OPNaJwAKy8PwcLSkVCcNzWaw3BSLZaYMFmXY8UgETSy%2BYAaxAuweADoNBoTVwuABOAAcHrMADYuB6yvKOJJlRb1ZxeAoQBozRb5nBYDBEChUJs6DFyJQ0Gn6LEgYZgAB9GleBhWvh0dbEKMQSJhyIhOoAT04puzbEEAHkGLQW6reFhRUZxP3SPhiJgHHgAG6YKOjzCqSdedZhw4VMO0PCRYjNjxYVu8Gl4FiH%2BZUAzABQANTwmAA7p2EoxDzJBCIxOwWvxBIoVOpR10eIDCMFBtUsfRtyjSB5lQBIqnnABaMZ0HBUxLGsMwNBuRCAHUxFoHDcMXGkmBw590EMRxkEQmJiBIBRIwqScqhcBh3E8Jo9CCSYihKbJklSARhmaRJBKqbo%2BJmVoWPacYRL0OxZIEDp6kk3pSgGToFNGcZ1OmUp5j1JYVj0GlMFWHg5UVUNRw1DhVA9H1EJ9SQbnzIwbggEsy0lCAtQwiCblwQgSCNE1SBuDwcxicKzFmI843mBBMCYLBYglUgbV2XZ7Swh5JEkD0Hg9BUHgeMwSv0TgQ1IU9JDde0FQ0LgfT9LgzDdBUfQDDQfVIFU1XsyNo1jft4yTCAkEWAgEhXTMIGzBJ01ieJMHwIhNJ/YRRHEb9ZD/NQw3vXcEjPaqOCVAaw3szsVzmxFUCoG5HOc1z3JA4AvJ8q0/Oi5bczihKxq0WZktS9LKGs4NeFPZr7Qaj0cq9B4NEkE0PTdaRBt4YbbFG81xutEAzAVe1vQDCrWpKvqCoVC7dlsoaIxB2VSATKBJqQJaVoWnncxAK9mASBQEFQAgK1oKsazrUcG2YYg%2BzbVMOwIbtezDQcCxHNVx1k2d5zVRdl1XUd1yDNUtx3PcMEso9iBPc6LyYK9bwfJ8X24Xhto/PbpG2w6ALVXRAwLMDApsK3oMyuCEM4ZCCFQ3YXnQqxLCwoiCKIkjd3I9aqLwGi6IYpi2mcCBXB00geMKDSBNyNIq5yISGH0/jRmYqcVPkziRhkrvqj03i6907Te9EsZOjbmYjP1UyynMu3oaunHwwcpyXLc4BkGQb6rl8ryArTmxgo2sLzAiqLUwB2KL7mRKidIFK0r6TLsrMe0Hk9GmzEqhVWourVeqjUzCujdBoTGJofTfweNdOyLMowxkJqDdmXMQAzQenza%2BK1uJny2rIX2X5/YHSUEdUcJ0mBnS9svJmuNOB3VmiuG4T0Xob3etvXe3l96/UPtgwGd9gbIMtE/CGr9oZAJAPDEqHoNBui4H1JGLVf5wOZhwEaSCkpZRJhoe0PoyoQNkbscBrkKqwKDIzFRdC1GswmvADmU0UwxTIBQRafC%2BjTmQAkBIhZpzukLH8MYhZVCuUltLSgss1Ty2bK%2BdsjA1Y9j7LrDY2tVi6zwBOKcBswzG2QCuO25BBAblHFbXcit9ypPto7ahfBLw3jvI%2BZ8KpTQ%2B12kQt88hSFBx0LafQYdU7WEgpEaOsF4JpHnAAehQuHY%2BASCCl2Un4Cu7Eq41ymO3MSDdhLj3ri3aemklID1Ug0bZHcy6DynsPAyike6ZAnkPWuVy5gLBMl%2BM0E4l4XRXjdTgwS3IsAUB4m4vjGqzMPuBE%2BIVNrhTKFfJx4VdiCM0TaUmgDYYgCKvaHKPpSagMxlIf09NV540QTY1Bdjpr3Xmi4/mfRdjVzwXoFpn5/DtMDsdU650gxfPgRwBhD1mHPV%2BTcf5gLgX2lBf5NxxB4WIsfs/SGmUgwSP/ron0dpJAlXkaVAM2NvnWJJUIsGWjWpNVdGqhqaMnI%2BgeGVBmtC14P1BtDMw9q8aGvmLOasaR0VAA).

Comment: Thanks. Could you please clarify whether the example in P.S. of the question is ill-formed as well?

Comment: @Fedor - It can't be (by the same bullet). Every source code occurrence of a lambda produces a unique type for that object. No hypothetical instantiation can produce the same sort of ill-formed construct after the definition (since there is no way to instantiate with the exact same lambda). Quirky how those things work out.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the original program is ill-formed due to https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp.res#general-8.4.

One can fix it by moving the template specialization ahead:

```
template<auto>
struct A{};

template<class = A<[]{ return 1; }>>
struct B;

template<auto z>
struct B<A<z>> {};

template<class>
struct B : B<> {};

B<int> x;
```

which is accepted now by both Clang and GCC: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/6TYdvTnMa